# how to wire two three way switch to a ceiling fan & add one switch for the fan and one for the light

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I have two three way switch when I'm closing one of them switch , the fan is automaticly close with the light & I hate that because it's a big place & I'm short so it's hard for me to grab the chain for closing the light to let the fan moving.So I want to add a switch for the fan only.The others switch will serve for the light. Someone help me please (show me a plan please )

Comment: You could buy a [new longer pull](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-Walnut-Wooden-Ball-Pull-Chain-7706900/203077850?N=5yc1vZbvn1) (~$3.00), or some [chain to extend the existing pull](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-Brass-3-ft-Beaded-Chain-with-Connector-7705000/203077837?N=5yc1vZbvn1) (~$3.00).

Comment: It's important to understand your existing condition for an accurate answer. Please confirm: You have a combination light/fan fixture operated together by switches from two locations. You want to convert so one switch controls only the fan, and the other controls only the light, correct? The fan/light assembly would need to have this be a possible option with separate terminals for fan and light. Since the light has a separate pull chain switch, this may not be possible without rewiring the fixture. It would be very difficult to help someone safely do this rewiring over the internet. Cont...

Comment: ...The other condition that is required for this to work is the two traveler wires for the 3-way switches must pass through the junction box for the fan/light fixture. There is a reasonable chance this is the case, but a fair chance it is not. If not, additional wires need to be run from one of the switches. In which case you probably are better off with a longer pull chain as Tester101 suggested.